# Can an NSPredicate search for an object within an array owned by an object in another array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've read the NSPredicate documentation and couldn't wrap my head around it all the way.  Simple predicates I can understand, but now how do I create a predicate for the following situation:

I have an array of Foo objects.  In the Foo class, one of the iVars is an NSMutableArray of Bar objects.  I need to filter the array of Foo objects to get those that have a particular Bar object in its array.  How?

Also, is it any easier (or possible) to find multiple Bar objects at once, or to combine several predicates that each search for a particular Bar?

Comment: Why do you want to use NSPredicate?

Comment: To filter an array.  There are theoretically an infinite number of filters that can be applied, and they need to be combined together, and this seems like the exact reason the filteredArrayUsingPredicate: method exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found what I'm looking for:

```
@class Foo {
  int var1;
  NSArray *barObjs;
}

predicate = @"var1 == 5 AND ANY barObjs.id == 5";
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question can be divided into two questions, and I'll try to answer them in order.

1. You can define a predicate on `Foo` instances that is true only when the instance's array of `Bar` objects contains a `Bar` instance matching a separate predicate. What you want is a `[SUBQUERY][1]` expression. A predicate string like this would match `Foo` instances with a `fooInt` value of 10 and with a `Bar` instance in the `barArray` property that has a `barInt` value of 1:

   @"fooInt==10 && SUBQUERY(barArray, $x, $x.barInt == 1).@count > 0"

   The general format for a SUBQUERY expression is `SUBQUERY(collection, $var, predicate)`. A `SUBQUERY` expression returns a collection of objects in `collection` that match `predicate`, so taking it's `@count` will tell you if the `Foo` instance has a `Bar` instance that matches the subquery predicate.
2. You can have an arbitrarily complex predicate within the `SUBQUERY` expression (including nested `SUBQUERY` expressions). Given that predicates containing SUBQUERY expressions are generally expensive to perform (they correspond roughly to a SQL `JOIN`), it's probably better to search for multiple `Bar` instances in one `SUBQUERY` expression using `OR` and then test for the appropriate `@count` in the result of the `SUBQUERY`. A predicate string like

   @"fooInt==10 && SUBQUERY(barArray, $x, $x.barInt == 1 || $x.barInt==2).@count >= 2"

   would find `Foo` instances that have a `Bar` instance with `barInt`==1 and a `Bar` instance with `barInt`==2 in the `Foo` instance's `barArray`.